# Custom PHP Spambot validator not working?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a simple PHP checkbox validator for my boss's website but my PHP code doesn't work. I've jimmied some basic checkbox code I found on the net, and tried working with an "if" statement but I get the same result whether I check the box or not.

Ideally I'd like to set it up where you have to check the box to prove you're not a spambot, not uncheck it. I'll settle for either solution though. How do I fix my code?

Live form: http://agentboris.com/listings/test-form.php

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="spambot" name="spambot" value="Yes" checked>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label for='spambot'><span class="parastyle grey">Uncheck box to show you are not a Spambot.</span></label><br><br />
```

PHP (condensed):

```
$spambot = $_POST['spambot'];

if ($spambot != 'Yes') {
    $spambot = 'No';
} 

if($spambot = 'Yes')
{
    echo "Please go back and uncheck the Spambot box.";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: `=` != `==` in your second `if`

Comment: `if($spambot = 'Yes')` is an assignment. Use `if($spambot == 'Yes')` for comparison

Comment: @andrewsi. if you want to make that an answer i'll mark it as correct, otherwise thanks, it worked.

Comment: @Alex Banman you always get de message "Please go back and uncheck the Spambot box." because `$spambot = 'Yes'` returns an String"Yes".
So `if($spambot = 'Yes')` that will execute as `if("Yes")` and that statement is always true. PHP should not allow an assignment within an if statement

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for the clarification, it seems i need to familiarize myself with php comparisons